# How to parse DataSnapshot returned by limitToLast in Flutter

Tags: flutter, parsing, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get the 'text' from the DataSnapshot returned from the Firebase Realtime Database in Flutter.

See this screenshot to understand how it looks like:

[image]

The following code is working fine but it returns null I think due to forEach callback function.

How can I get the value of text so that I can return it correctly in the function returning `Future`.

```
Future<String> getLastMessageOfConversation(String uid) async {
    DataSnapshot dataSnapshot = await FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .reference()
        .child(ChatService.PRIVATE_CHAT)
        .child(uid)
        .limitToLast(1)
        .once();

    if (dataSnapshot.value != null) {
      dataSnapshot.value.forEach(
        (index, data) {
          MessageModel messageModel = MessageModel.fromJson(data);
          return messageModel.text;
        },
      );
    } else
      return "";
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to return content from the anonymous function of the forEach loop. It does not return the data to the getLastMessageOfConversation function. Tha's why null is being returned.

Check this code.

```
Future<String> getLastMessageOfConversation(String uid) async {
    DataSnapshot dataSnapshot = await FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .reference()
        .child(ChatService.PRIVATE_CHAT)
        .child(uid)
        .limitToLast(1)
        .once();

    String message = '';
    if (dataSnapshot.value != null) {
      dataSnapshot.value.forEach(
        (index, data) {
          MessageModel messageModel = MessageModel.fromJson(data);
          message =  messageModel.text;
        },
      );
    }
  return message;
  }
```